# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext .NET Core with SQL Server

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have been banging my head against a wall with this one and have been googling to no avail.

I have just started a new ASP.NET Core MVC project, I have installed/updated my packages for these two to 2.2.0:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

I have set the project to expect .NET Core 2.2.0 as well.

I am able to successfully add my table schemas with this command in Package Manager console to scaffold the Database, so I know the connection string is fine/working:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "SERVER=Server\Instance;DATABASE=Database;UID=user;PWD=password;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Tables Table1, Table2, Table3
```

The created model file, `DatabaseDBContext.cs` looks like this:

```
public partial class DatabaseDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseDBContext()
    {
    }

    public DatabaseDBContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseDBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

This also contains a method that works to retrieve my scaffold data, but isn't considered safe for production use so I commented this out:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("SERVER=Server\\Instance;DATABASE=Database;UID=user;PWD=password;");
    }
}
```

I added this same connection string to the `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConnString": "SERVER=Server\\Instance;DATABASE=Database;UID=user;PWD=password;"
  }
}
```

I then added the `DbContext` to the `startup.cs` file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnString")));
}
```

Trying to add a new scaffolded controller for one of the tables throws this error:

> Finding the generator 'controller'...
>   Running the generator 'controller'...
>   Attempting to compile the application in memory.
>   Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'TableName'
>
> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
>
> StackTrace:
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.Initialize(IServiceProvider scopedProvider, IDbContextOptions contextOptions, DbContext context)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
>
> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Has anyone got any clue what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to remove he parameterless constructor?

Comment: Yes, weirdly if I comment that out, instead it complains that there is no parameter less constructor available!

Comment: You mentioned OnConfiguring is commented out, is that correct? Or are you missing base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder); at the end on the OnConfiguring override method?

Comment: Also do you have any instances in the code where you try to use the DatabaseDBContext currently?

Comment: The plot thickens a little. If I uncomment the OnConfiguring optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer statement then I can add the scaffolded controller. I can then recomment the optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer statement and everything still works code wise using the startup services AddDbContext. As a workaround that sort of works, but it's weird, as it seems to be unhappy specifically when trying to add the scaffold content.

Comment: RE: the OnConfiguring section, I had it completely commented out, but even if I just comment the if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) lines, the result is the same. I don't have anything else in the OnConfiguring section except what you see in my original post.

Comment: Try with adding this `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` to `DBConnString`.

Comment: So I fixed but it in a really roundabout way. My new project was originally on an older version of .net core. I had updated the version but there must have been something it didn't like during the update. I created a new project and started it on 2.2.0, then it worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I fixed but it in a really roundabout way. My new project was originally on an older version of .net core. I had updated the version but there must have been something it didn't like during the update. I created a new project and started it on 2.2.0, then it worked...

The code logic was sound above. Still needed the same packages:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Startup.cs seems quite different, so maybe if anyone else sees this they could try updating the startup.cs code:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseDBConnString")));

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Had to add a reference to startup.cs for this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

That was needed for the AddDbContext method to resolve.

After doing this the scaffolding now works. So it's fixed, but it required me to start over to fix it.

Comment: Same is happening with v3.0.0 preview 6. Mi first thinking is that the scaffolder is not ready to pick the Context instance from the DI container. So I UNCOMMENTED the OnConfiguring overriding and it worked. After the controller creation, I commented out again and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and this solved it for me (setting UseSqlServer in OnConfiguring):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    if (!builder.IsConfigured)
    {
        string conn = this.IsProduction ? Const.ProductionConnectionString : Const.LocalDBConnectionString;

        builder.UseSqlServer(conn);
    }

    base.OnConfiguring(builder);
}
```

Comment: Where are you declaring Const.ProductionConnectionString? I can't get it out of the configuration section like I can in startup.cs.

Comment: @HungryHippos oh sorry thats a custom extension method retuning one of two const string's containg either connectionstring to local or production. I don't know if this helps your issue, but the error was fixed when I specified UseSqlServer in OnConfiguring, even if I set it up on startup.

Comment: So I fixed but it in a really roundabout way. My new project was originally on an older version of .net core. I had updated the version but there must have been something it didn't like during the update. I created a new project and started it on 2.2.0, then it worked...

Comment: @HungryHippos great, nothing is better than that :)

Comment: This fixed it for me. If you are getting this error from an MVC project where you are trying to scaffold some data entry pages, you can put anything in the connection string as the scaffolding code will use the connection string from your MVC project.

Answer (score 1):

After battleing with this issue I've encounter the solution for it here

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12331

The problem was that Add-Migration was expecting the CreateWebHostBuilder

`public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)`

Before my `public static void Main(string[])` was running the WebHost without the static CreateWebHostBuilder and that after I added the Static function then it worked.

Comment: I did the same thing for a Console app that I wanted to create to test a few things... my method ended up being `public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)` and it worked as well. (just because the WebHost naming annoyed me, not being a Web app and all) Additionally, this eliminated the error about missing a "parameterless constructor" on the `DbContext`. I'm using an older EF Core ~ 3.1, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

It was wired but fixed this issue by updating the framework version of the project solution. For example, I created one core repo on 3.0 and later installed the latest version 3.1 on the system so it was expecting to be updated with the latest version. I changed it and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used services to communicate with database and UnitOfWork, but in service constructor I have not dependency injection and just made new instance of DbContext class. It worked fine if I had hardocde DbContextOptionsBuilder in context which generates automatically, but in case of moving it to program.cs I got this error.
Problem solved by using dependency injection in service constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one constructor in the application DbContext:

```
public DatabaseDBContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseDBContext> options)
        :
        base(options)
    {
    }
```

Then make sure you use DI when accessing the context:

```
private DatabaseDBContext _context;

public AccountService(DatabaseDBContext context)
{
_context = context;
}

public async Task DoSomething()
{
 /*...*/
 _context.Add(something);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem after I've inlined `Program.CreateWebHostBuilder` into `Program.Main`. Had to extract it back.

Comment: Not showing any code or what you did is not the stackoverflow way please provide some code

Answer (score -3):

Try add this 3rd constructor:

```
public DatabaseDBContext()
{
}

public DatabaseDBContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseDBContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

public DatabaseDBContext(DbContextOptions options)
    : base(options)
{
}
```

Then chuck a breakpoint in each one just so you are sure which one is actually getting used.

Comment: Didn't seem to help unfortunately, gave me an error on the 3rd one about it being ambiguous. Thanks anyway! :) Also not sure why but none of the breakpoints were being hit.

Comment: Oh yeah, you would have to remove the other constructor.  I guess that didn't help either!

Comment: So I fixed but it in a really roundabout way. My new project was originally on an older version of .net core. I had updated the version but there must have been something it didn't like during the update. I created a new project and started it on 2.2.0, then it worked...

Comment: breakpoints wouldn't be hit during scaffolding