# Pass connection string to .Net Core EF library from another library

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application, which is structured in three layers i.e.:

- Data access layer (Entity Framework)
- Business logic layer
- ASP.NET MVC web application

As it is right now, the configuration works, and I can access my database in my web application library. However, when I constructed my data access layer with EF Db first, I got a generic class, which looks something like this:

```
public partial class ClassContext: DbContext
{
    public ClassContext(DbContextOptions<ClassContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Entity> Entity{ get; set; }
    ....

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("ConnString");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the connection string is hardcoded into my `OnConfiguring` method, which is not recommended.

Therefore, I followed the following "guide" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which suggest me to use the built in DI, to pass the connection string from my Web library.

This I did:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Add connectionstring to EF
    services.AddDbContext<ClassContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStringFromAppSettings")));
}
```

According to the "guide" the connectionstring should be provided to the constructor of my `ClassContext` class - and it sort of does, however not with any connection string..

This means, that `optionsBuilder.IsConfigured` evaluates false, and wants to use the hard coded connectionstring.

Therefore, I would very much like to know, if I use the DI incorrect, since i cannot access the connection string in my `ClassContext` class

**Update**

I removed the `OnConfiguring()` method, and do now inject the context into my service class constructor in the business logic layer the following way:

```
public MasterService(ClassContext context)
{
    MinorService = new MinorService(context);
}

public Stuff AddStuffIntoDatabase(Stuff test)
{
    //business logic going before here
   MinorService.addstuffMethod(test) 
}
```

However, now I get the following error, when I want to do an operation in my database:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.

This did not happen before, when I configured the connectionstring wrongly in my `OnConfiguring()` method.

Comment: You don't have to add the connectionstring again in the OnConfiguring method. That method is called _before_ the DbContext is configured. That is why it evaluates to false. Just adding the connectionstring in ConfigureServices is enough. The DbContextOptionsBuilder will already be configured to use sql server when OnConfiguring is called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have just made an update to my question :-)

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57980799/3883866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the appsettings.json? Is it like this?

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionStringFromAppSettings": "your_connection_string"
  }
```

Configuration.GetConnectionString always search for the section "ConnectionStrings"

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Is the json block you use for the connection string exactly matching the one in the answer?

Comment: Yes it is. It is a mssql server so i have the following: `"Data source=IP_ADDRESS; Initial catalog=DB; User UD = ID; Password=PW"`